# Error Upgrade Magento in 2.3.4 --> 2.4.1

Tags: magento2

After upgrade with composer in magento 2.4.1
I launch command after clean cache : php -d memory_limit=-1 bin/magento setup:upgrade
But i have this error :

```
Upgrading data.. Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Filter\DateTime, Argument 1 passed to Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Filter\DateTime::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime, instance of FernandoFauth\DateTime\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime\Filter\DateTime given, called in /var/www/vhosts/vedelbois2.quatrys.fr/httpdocs/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 121
```

I don't understand this error i can't found a answer on the web.

Anyone can help me ?

Please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's beacause the module : FernandoFauth_DateTime
:( it's ok now !!